# Controlling the speed of Manipulate animations exported to SWF

Tags: export, manipulate

I would like to export in .swf a "Manipulation" output. I am using

```
 Export["Pi.swf", Manipulate[SeedRandom[n];
  data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, 2}];
  insidepts = Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x^2 + y^2 < 1];
  inside = Length[insidepts];
  Text@Style[
    Column[{Graphics[{PointSize[0.0001], Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Blue, 
        GeometricTransformation[
         Line[{{Offset[{-2, 2}, {0, 0}], 
            Offset[{2, -2}, {0, 0}]}, {Offset[{-2, -2}, {0, 0}], 
            Offset[{2, 2}, {0, 0}]}}], Dynamic[data]]}, 
       ImageSize -> If[format, 500, 350]], 
      Row[{"inside: ", inside, "\toutside: ", m - inside, "\ttotal: ",
         m}], Row[{"π=4 x ", inside, "/", m, " = ", 4. inside/m}]}], 
    "Label"], {{n, 1, "random seed"}, 1, 1000, 1, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m, 1, "sample size"}, 1, 5000, 1, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{format, False, "large format"}, {True, 
    False}}, AutorunSequencing -> {1, 2}]]
```

I think it is too fast... Is there a way to modify speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the *Mathematica* help on `AutorunSequencing`, a solution would be to set `AutorunSequencing -> {{1, x1}, {2, x2}}` as an option in your `Manipulate`,
where `x1` and `x2` are numbers indicating how long in seconds the sequence is to run.

Answer (score 6):

The [reference page for "SWF"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/SWF.html) indicates that there is a "FrameRate" option.  Larger values of "FrameRate" takes longer to generate and creates a larger file, but should make the animation run more slowly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The thing is that I tried that, first thing but I cannot see any difference no matter what speed I choose. The syntax I am using is `Export["Pi.swf",Manipulate[...],"FrameRate"->5]`.