# How to include Mathematica animation in a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: export, animation, office

**Note: Cross-posted at [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/115317?p_p_auth=wS2u1RIb)**

I want to include a Mathematica animation in PowerPoint presentation.
My code is:

```
poskus = Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
   Dynamic@{{GrayLevel[.3], Line[space[[1 ;; t]]]}, {Blue, 
      PointSize[.015], Point[space[[t]]]},}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
   AxesLabel -> {"x [nm]", "y [nm]", "z [nm]"}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 700, 
   BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thick], 
   PlotRange -> {{-2620, 1600}, {-1700, 1450}, {-3500, 350}}, 
   SphericalRegion -> True], 
  Row[{Control[{t, 1, Length[data], 1, Animator, ImageSize -> Small, 
      AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> 50, 
      AnimationRepetitions -> 1}], Spacer[10], 
    Dynamic["time = " <> ToString[data[[t, 1]]]]}], FrameMargins -> 0]
```

I want to place the animation into the PowerPoint slide so that the first frame is shown. Then I want to start it by mouse click. It should stop in the end position and wait for my next mouse click (for next slide). How can I achieve it?

The best I could get was when exporting to swf. But the problem is that it runs immediately after I reach the slide. And it doesn't stop at the end, but it goes in reverse direction and then forward ... It is also very fast. And my computer becomes slow. The file size (test.swf) is 146 KB.

Some things I would like to know:

- How to export without the sliders showing
- which format best to use
- how to influence the frame rate, length and direction of the animation
- how to most conveniently integrate the animation into PowerPoint

**Edit**

Sample of my data: first column is time multiplied by a factor, the others are coordinates.

```
data={{0.146, -160.582, 125.712, 20.1735}, {0.288, -192.582, 182.712, 
  58.1735}, {0.431, -207.582, 237.712, 201.174}, {0.576, -250.582, 
  134.712, 162.174}, {0.723, -234.582, 226.712, 
  292.174}, {0.877, -259.582, 236.712, 175.174}, {1.02, -303.582, 
  241.712, 61.1735}, {1.16, -362.582, 282.712, 
  17.1735}, {1.3, -448.582, 268.712, 114.174}, {1.45, -309.582, 
  188.712, 87.1735}, {1.58, -275.582, 193.712, 
  31.1735}, {1.73, -142.582, 182.712, -67.8265}, {1.88, -296.582, 
  257.712, -41.8265}, {2.02, -412.582, 
  307.712, -80.8265}, {2.16, -389.582, 
  366.712, -119.826}, {2.31, -337.582, 
  402.712, -273.826}, {2.46, -470.582, 
  499.712, -179.826}, {2.6, -432.582, 
  546.712, -208.826}, {2.76, -386.582, 
  539.712, -339.826}, {2.9, -467.582, 
  429.712, -377.826}, {3.05, -479.582, 
  462.712, -338.826}, {3.18, -514.582, 
  383.712, -239.826}, {3.32, -592.582, 
  279.712, -169.826}, {3.46, -574.582, 
  313.712, -134.826}, {3.61, -575.582, 
  262.712, -198.826}, {3.74, -542.582, 
  269.712, -241.826}, {3.89, -570.582, 
  201.712, -179.826}, {4.04, -637.582, 
  156.712, -128.826}, {4.19, -784.582, 155.712, 
  30.1735}, {4.33, -837.582, 212.712, 31.1735}, {4.48, -750.582, 
  144.712, -121.826}, {4.62, -858.582, 110.712, 
  58.1735}, {4.76, -880.582, 41.7125, -70.8265}, {4.89, -884.582, 
  117.712, -171.826}, {5.04, -874.582, 
  56.7125, -209.826}, {5.2, -924.582, -11.2875, -228.826}, {5.35, \
-896.582, -38.2875, -270.826}, {5.5, -869.582, -44.2875, -317.826}, \
{5.64, -915.582, -132.288, -221.826}, {5.8, -971.582, -51.2875, \
-349.826}, {5.94, -992.582, -95.2875, -377.826}, {6.08, -1060.58, \
-5.2875, -266.826}, {6.23, -1054.58, 
  3.7125, -431.826}, {6.38, -1099.58, 
  31.7125, -505.826}, {6.53, -1211.58, 
  85.7125, -477.826}, {6.68, -1203.58, 
  108.712, -508.826}, {6.83, -1001.58, 
  67.7125, -649.826}, {6.98, -1051.58, -1.2875, -675.826}}
```

Comment: There used to be a commercial product M for ActiveX from Episoft that allowed the inclusion of M in PP. Don't know if it's still around.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473799/can-we-show-some-dynamics-cdf-in-powerpoint-or-keynote

Comment: Related to the SWF speed concerns: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/

Comment: Adding to @Vitaliy Kaurovs suggestions, I can recommend MP4 (.mov) animations, the export of which is described here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4236/131 . These work nicely in PowerPoint, offer the full color range and even display basic play/pause controls on mouseover.

Comment: can power point be converted to PDF? if so, it is easier to insert animations in PDF files. Then the final PDF file can be used instead of PPT for presentation.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Nasser PowerPoint can be easily converted to PDF. I use Windows.

Comment: Without you supplying `data` or a minimum working example reproducing your animation is impossible.

Comment: How can I upload my file animacija.txt here?

Comment: Best would be to come up with a small test sample that can be pasted here. Or host your file somewhere and insert the file link directly in your code.

Comment: *Please* do format your data in a useable form (e.g. as a list with the correct structure). Think: How would *I* like a question to look like to make me want to spend time to answer?

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to browse. Since it seem you also posted the same question on Wolfram Community, it is a good idea to include this information in your question to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My preferred embedding option is to [export to MP4 Quicktime (.mov)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4236/131). Taking a few bovine lines from the [2012 Oneliner competition](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=282&video=1281):

```
{g, p} := {ExampleData@{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, g[[1, 2, 1]]};
ani = Table[
   g /. g[[1, 2, 3]] -> VertexColors -> (Hue@Random[] & /@ p) /. 
    p -> (# (x - (1 - x)/Sqrt[#.#]) & /@ p), {x, 0, 1, .01}];    
framerate = 10;

ListAnimate[ani, framerate, AnimationRepetitions -> 1] (*preview*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now for exporting (note the direct export of the separate frames):

```
 Export["mooo.mov", ani, "VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video", "FrameRate" -> framerate]
```

> (*"mooo.mov"*)

The resulting movie imports and embeds nicely into PowerPoint (via Insert->Video->Video from file), and you get the full set of play/pause... controls during animation, see e.g. this screenshot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use all kinds of PPT format [mumbo-jumbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mumbo_jumbo_%28phrase%29):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your code has some other issues too, but with slight modifications this seems to work:

```
frames = Table[
   Graphics3D[{{GrayLevel[.3], Thick, Line[space[[1 ;; t]]]}, {Blue, 
      PointSize[.015], Point[space[[t]]]},}, Axes -> True, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
     AxesLabel -> {"x [nm]", "y [nm]", "z [nm]"}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 700, 
    BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thick], 
    PlotRange -> {{-2620, 1600}, {-1700, 1450}, {-3500, 350}}, 
    SphericalRegion -> True], {t, 1, Length[space]}];

Export["test.mov", frames, "VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video", 
 "FrameRate" -> 1]
```

Comment: If I export it to MP4 Quicktime the controls (slider) are there. It is not the same as in your example ...

Comment: @Luka to be expected - why not generate a set of frames (like shown above) and export those?

Comment: I don't know how to create a set of frames from 3D data (x, y, z coordinates), because I also need "the pointer"- a ball that is showing the path. I want to show the random walk of an electron, so the location of the electron must be shown through all the animation.

Comment: @Luka Your `Manipulate` already works. You take the `Graphics3D` part of that and generate `t` values e.g. in a `Table` to get your frames. But without your example working helping you is difficult.

Comment: it is exactly what I need. Thank you very much. Now I need just a codec because PowerPoint cannot import the movie. It says that 64-bit codec for this media format must be installed.

Comment: @Luka Try installing an appropriate QuickTime player, that worked for me in several cases.

Answer (score 28):

Read comments to your post - many good links there. Additionally, are a few thoughts on the topic.

1) Avoid PPT, - use built-in Mathematica slideshow templates, they were recently updated and are beautiful. Advantage is - you preserve computations and native graphics (like rotations in 3D, etc.). You can read more in this post: [**Best way to give presentations with Mathematica**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61/13)

2) If you must use PPT, then Export to [**.GIF**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GIF.html) file. I see you tried [**.SWF**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/SWF.html), this may work too, but you had some problems. Here are solutions with .GIF file

- Read: [**How to Export this animation as a gif file for powerpoint presentation**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/13)
- Read: [**Showcasing Manipulate[…] via .GIF animations**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994)
- To slow down increase the number of produced image frames
- Also you can try "DisplayDurations"->{t1, t2, t3, ...} to set the display durations for each frame ("AnimationDuration" for .SWF files)
- "AnimationRepetitions" - > 1 for playing just single time and stoping  (for .SWF "RepeatAnimation" -> False)
- To make .GIF playable on click [**read this tutorial**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/add-a-movie-or-animated-gif-to-a-slide-HP005194674.aspx)

3) The last exotic option is to [**make a CDF file, embed it into a web page**](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/cdf/) and then use [**LiveWeb**](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm#.UiOo2mR4ZXI) ( [**tutorial**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25946/how-to-add-live-web-pages-to-a-powerpoint-presentation/) ) to display the webpage in PPT. Very experimental, no guarantees, I did not try it myself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I need some time to go through all the suggestions and find the one which fits my needs the best.

Comment: GIF has the advantage that animated gifs are actually embedded in ppt. For Any other format ppt links to an external file, resulting in unending headaches should you ever move your files around.  The downside to the gif is that it just plays with no control even to pause etc.

Comment: The ppt works fine with imported swf. It is fast ..

Comment: @george2079 movs are also embedded. The onyl issue is that you need e.g. the correct quicktime player (32/64bit etc.).

Comment: I didn't try with LiveWeb, but I can confirm that a WebBrowser object will display a functioning CDF embedded into a web page.

Comment: +1 I always use GIFs for animations in ppt. Works on every computer without codec hassel. Dithering may be a problem though if many colors are present.

Comment: @Ajasja GIFs tend to bloat for non-uniform images / backgrounds. For my example compare 3.3MB GIF to 600kB MOV.

Comment: @YvesKlett Indeed, but that is usually not a problem (I've used 200MB gifs in my presentations without any drawbacks). The lack of playback control is irks me much more.

Comment: @Ajasja I shudder when I imagine the `Export` time for a 200MB gif. And then reducing true color to indexed... but what sold me on the .mov is the smooth playback control.