# Exporting Animated gif

Tags: animation

I am trying to export an animated gif to my desktop but when I do so and open it, the image doesn't move. I've tried with avi and it works.The only reason that I'm exporting as a gif is to the incorporate it into Beamer. Does avi work just as well?

```
Export["N:\\new.gif",ListAnimate[{a // MatrixForm, b // MatrixForm, c // MatrixForm, 
       d // MatrixForm}, 1]]
```

Is there anything wrong in the input for this to happen?

Comment: I'm not sure if it wil be ok, second argument for export gifs should be a list of images. You can try  `Rasterize/@(MatrixForm/@{a,b,c,d})`. Ok, I've tried, `Rasterize` is redundant. `Export[..., MatrixForm/@{a,b,c,d}]` will work.

Comment: [How to export animation as gif](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478) - duplicate? and related source of useful links [how to create animation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31513/5478)

Comment: I have marked this one as a duplicate since the source of the problem is now apparent.  As you can see, including a self-contained example (like your recent question) is more likely to produce correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem cames from bad use of Export[ ].

Export's second argument must be a list, and in your code it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

```
a = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}];
b = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}];
arrays = {Image[ArrayPlot[a]], Image[ArrayPlot[b]]};
Export["arrays.gif", arrays]
```

[image]