# presentation of 3D image only

Tags: graphics3d

For viewing or discussion is it possible to display a mouse rotatable ParametricPlot3D or Manipulate holding back Mathematica code lines in a slideshow for example?

Comment: Hi! Your question is a bit unclear.  Do you want to show a Graphica3D object in the frontend without showing code? Or display graphics in e.g.  PowerPoint?

Comment: @Yves Klett Carry graphics only to a new location in a Powerpoint, word etc.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31511/131

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you move your mouse to the right and double-click on the output, the input should be hidden.